# How to get the Attribute name and the Elemnt value using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Web Forms application and .NET 4.0. I don't have previous experience with XML in .NET. I created this very simple XML document from which I want to extract the attributes with their respective data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <DataTable>
    <Filter>true</Filter>
    <DropDown>true</DropDown>
  </DataTable>  
</configuration>
```

And I try this code:

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/XML/Settings.xml");
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

IEnumerable<XElement> xnodes = xdoc.Root.Elements("DataTable");

List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (XElement xnn in xnodes)
{
   list.Add(xnn.Value);
}
```

which results in in one element in my `List` with value `truetrue`. I know here I don't try to get both the attribute name and the content inside it, but in general that's what I wanna do, so how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute here. I think you want a dictionary where keys are the *element* names and values are  *element* values

```
var dictionary = xdoc.Root.Elements("DataTable").Elements()
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => (string)x)
```

Comment: Hmm, indeed I want a `Dictionary` which looks like: `key = Filter, value = true; key = DropDown, value = true`. What I get until now and trying your suggestions too is `key = DataTable, value = truetrue`.

Comment: @Leron add .Elements() after .Elements("DataTable")

Answer (score 0):

You can get all elements as dictionary

```
 var dictionary = xdoc.Descendants().
     ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => x.Value)
```

---

Answer (score -1):

had you tried using the `XmlConvert.ToBoolean()` function?

Also, I would have preferred to use Linq syntax when working with XML files.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ2XML yet. For now just want to get it working, then I'll maybe try to implement it with LINQ. Can you explain where to use this `XmlConvert` func?

Comment: I was thinking you might do this: `list.Add(XmlConvert.ToBoolean(xnn.Value));` I did not test it myself, but it might be a first step towards a solution.